# Bulk insert sin tener una tabla de destino creada

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

estoy realizando un bulk insert para importar datos de un csv a SQL server. La forma en que lo hago es crear la tabla y luego a traves del bulk cargo las filas. Pero resulta tedioso especificar todas las columnas al crear la tabla, ya que me llegó un archivo con 88 columnas. ¿Existe alguna manera de crear los campos automaticamente sin especificarlos?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede, pero es algo que requiere de bastante código.

Tienes que hacer varias cosas.

Lo primero es generar la inserción en una tabla temporal. Luego utilizar alguna función que te separe por el carácter que venga en el csv, pero que te devuelva las filas en el mismo orden. Existen varias desarrolladas como delimitedSplit8k o Earlands split_me entre otras. Cuando ya puedes separar el contenido de lo importado, ya puedes preparar una query dinámica por las filas que te devuelva esta separación. Por ejemplo si te vienen 10 columnas en el csv, al separarlas tendrás 10 filas. Con estas 10 filas tendrás que crear una query dinámica para generar la creación de la tabla. Luego tendrás que ejecutar un pivot dinámico para insertar tu consulta en la tabla destino.

Puedes revisar esto mismo en este artículo, con la salvedad de que se hace para un número de columnas estáticas, por tanto solo tendrás que incorporar la parte del pivot dinámico.

[Leer csv e insertar en tabla](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/16/leer-archivo-de-texto-o-csv-e-insertar-en-tabla/)

[Pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)